# Cordova FileEntry.file() returning size 0

Tags: filesystems, filereader

I'm running into an issue where when I save a jpg as an octet-stream on windows, the subsequent read returns a file with size of 0.  I can see the file on my hard drive, and the file looks fine, but reading the file fails.

The code below is what I'm using to interact with the file system, with some hacks thrown in to try to solve this issue.

```
function downloadFileFromUrl(url, localPath, contentType, successCallback, failureCallback) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    xhr.responseType = 'blob';

    xhr.onload = function () {
        if (this.status == 200) {
            localPath = encodeURI(localPath);
            writePersistantFile(localPath, this.response, true, contentType,
                function (fileEntry) {
                    if (successCallback != undefined) {
                        successCallback(fileEntry);
                    }
                },
                function (error) {
                    if (failureCallback != undefined) {
                        failureCallback(error);
                    }
                });
        }
    };
    xhr.send();
}

function createDirectoryRecursively(path, parentDir, callback, errorCallback) {
    if (path == null || path.length == 0) {
        callback(parentDir);
        return;
    }
    var index = path.indexOf('/');
    var dirName = null;
    var remainder = null;
    if (index <= 0) {
        dirName = path;
    } else {
        dirName = path.substring(0, index);
        remainder = path.substring(index + 1);
    }

    parentDir.getDirectory(dirName, { create: true, exclusive: true }, function (dirEntry) {
        self.createDirectoryRecursively(remainder, dirEntry, callback, errorCallback);
    }, function (error) {
        if (error.code == 12) {
            parentDir.getDirectory(dirName, { create: false }, function (dirEntry) {
                self.createDirectoryRecursively(remainder, dirEntry, callback, errorCallback);
            }, function (error2) {
                errorCallback(error);
            });
            return;
        }
        errorCallback(error);
    });
}

function getFile(fileName, parentDir, callback, errorCallback) {
    if (parentDir == null) {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,
            function (fs) {
                getFile(fileName, fs.root, callback, errorCallback);
            },
            function (error) {

            });
        return;
    }
    if (fileName.indexOf('/') >= 0) {
        var dirName = fileName.substring(0, fileName.lastIndexOf('/'));
        createDirectoryRecursively(dirName, parentDir,
            function (directory) {
                var name = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
                getFile(name, directory, callback, errorCallback);
            }, errorCallback);
        return;
    }
    parentDir.getFile(fileName, { create: true },
        function (fileEntry) {
            console.log('obtained file');
            callback(fileEntry);
        },
        function (error) {
            if (error.code == 1) {
                parentDir.getFile(fileName, { create: false },
                    function (fileEntry) {
                        console.log('obtained file');
                        callback(fileEntry);
                    },
                    function (error) {
                        if (error.code == 12) {
                            return;
                        }
                        errorCallback(error);
                    });
                return;
            }
            errorCallback(error);
        });
}

function readPersistantFile(filePath, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    getFile(filePath, null,
        function (fileEntry) {
            console.log('obtained file');
            fileEntry.file(function (file) {
                console.log('file size: ' + file.size);
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onloadend = function () {
                    console.log("Successful file read");
                    if (successCallback != undefined) {
                        successCallback(this.result);
                    }
                };

                var extension = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
                if (extension == 'json') {
                    reader.readAsText(file);
                } else {
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
                }
            });

        },
        function (error) {
            console.log('An error occured while getting the file');
            console.error(error);
            if (errorCallback != undefined) {
                errorCallback(error);
            }
        });
}

function writePersistantFile(filePath, data, isBinary, contentType, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    var dataSize = (data.length != undefined) ? data.length : (data.size != undefined)? data.size : 5 * 1024 * 1024;
    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, dataSize, function (fs) {
        console.log('file system opened: ' + fs.name);

        var lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf('/');
        var directory = filePath.substring(0, lastIndex);
        createDirectoryRecursively(directory, fs.root, function (parentDir) {
            console.log('Directory created');
            var fileName = filePath.substring(lastIndex + 1);
            getFile(fileName, parentDir,
                function (fileEntry) {
                    console.log('obtained file');
                    fileEntry.createWriter(function (fileWriter) {
                        console.log('created writer');
                        if (typeof (data) == 'string') {
                            fileWriter.write(new Blob([data], { type: contentType }));
                        } else {
                            fileWriter.write(data);
                        }

                        if (successCallback != undefined) {
                            successCallback(fileEntry);
                        }
                    });
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log('An error occured while getting the file');
                    console.error(error);
                    if (errorCallback != undefined) {
                        errorCallback(error);
                    }
                });

        }, function (error) {
            console.log('An error occured while saving the file');
            console.error(error);
            if (errorCallback != undefined) {
                errorCallback(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears not to be the code above, which can be easily optimized, but rather the length / number of folders being passed in.

The same file being written had a length of 36 characters and 4 subfolders.  Changing this to just a single file name such as 'page-1.jpg' worked without issue.